# How can i overwrite bash command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I start using [exa](https://github.com/ogham/exa) and I need to use `l` as an alias for `exa`. I added `alias l="exa"` but the default `l` runs before the alias one. How can I disable it?

Comment: What is the default `l`? AFAIK, `l` is alias for `ls` in ubuntu. Remove that definition from `bashrc` or add your alias later, so it can override it.

Comment: @vish4071 ```ls``` used to list all dirs and files, but ```l```  list all of them including the hidden ones.

Comment: Oh, alright. But I assure you, `l` is not a "command" in linux. If it is also displaying hidden files, then its alias must be defined as: `alias l="ls -a"` Just remove this line. Or add your alias as the last line of `bashrc`.

Comment: @vish4071 Oh, my mistake. I'm using zsh and didn't even look at bashrc. Thanks!

Comment: Oh dear!! Edit `zshrc` then :)